# Nightwatch.js can't iterate over a set returned from a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, promise, nightwatch.js

I use Nightwatch.js with Typescript. In a test, first, I need to read some values from a column from a table on a page. Then I need to loop over values I just got and apply a filter using a value, so the table shows only rows containing the value used with the filter. I decided that I collect the values as a set to avoid duplicates and retern the set as a Promise:

```
    getNumbers(browser: NightwatchBrowser) {
            return new Promise<Set<string>>(function (resolve, reject) {
                browser
                    .useXpath()
                    .waitForElementPresent('//div[contains(text(),"Num")]')
                    .useCss()
                    .elements('xpath', '//div[contains(text(),"Num")]', function (result) {
                        const numSet: Set<string> = new Set();
                        Object(result.value).forEach(item => {
                            browser.elementIdText(item.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                                numSet.add(String(result.value).replace(/\D/g, ''));
                            })
                        });
                    resolve(numSet);
                    });
            });
        }
```

That works well. I debugged it and saw that the set contains data. Then I'm trying to iterate over the set in a loop:

```
    'Validate the filter applies correctly.': browser => {
            myPage.getNumbers(browser)
                .then(function (numSet) {
                    // debug output -- prints at the very beginning "Set:  Set {}" 
                    console.log('Set: ', numSet);
                    // another debug output -- prints "Set { '2000','0007' }" later, after getNumbers() is executed
                    browser.perform(done => {
                        console.log(numSet);
                       done();
                    });
                    for (const digits of numSet) {  
                        log(`Applying filter for: ${digits}`); // -- never printed
                        myPage
                            .click('@FILTER_BTN`enter code here`')
                            .apply(digits)
                        };
                    });
            });
        },
```

forEach or for loop always exits, becuase at that phase of test execution the set is empty. So, my question is how I can fix my code, so it can iterate over the the non-empty set returned from the Promise?

Comment: Is it `cardSet` or `numSet`?

Comment: Can you change that to `console.log('Set: ', numSet.size);`?

Comment: the log output of numSet.size is 0

Comment: Is `browser.elementIdText` asynchronous?

Comment: Definitely, yes!